# Failed to start SonarQube, Unable to start JVM: Permission denied (13)

Tags: java, sonarqube, sonarqube5.1

Failed to start SonarQube.

How can I fix it?

**Sonar Config:**

```
sonar.jdbc.username=sonar
sonar.jdbc.password=sonar
sonar.jdbc.url=jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/sonar?useUnicode=true&characterEncoding=utf8&rewriteBatchedStatements=true&useConfigs=maxPerformance
sonar.jdbc.maxActive=20
sonar.jdbc.maxIdle=5
sonar.jdbc.minIdle=2
sonar.jdbc.maxWait=5000
sonar.jdbc.timeBetweenEvictionRunsMillis=30000
sonar.web.javaOpts=-server -Xmx768m -XX:MaxPermSize=160m -XX:+HeapDumpOnOutOfMemoryError
sonar.web.host=0.0.0.0
sonar.web.port=9000
```

**Wrapper Config**

```
wrapper.java.command=/usr/local/jdk1.8.0_45/bin/

wrapper.java.additional.1=-Djava.awt.headless=true
wrapper.java.mainclass=org.tanukisoftware.wrapper.WrapperSimpleApp
wrapper.java.classpath.1=../../lib/jsw/*.jar
wrapper.java.classpath.2=../../lib/*.jar
wrapper.java.library.path.1=./lib
wrapper.app.parameter.1=org.sonar.application.App
wrapper.java.initmemory=3
wrapper.java.maxmemory=32


wrapper.console.format=PM
wrapper.console.loglevel=DEBUG
wrapper.logfile=../../logs/sonar.log
wrapper.logfile.format=M
wrapper.logfile.loglevel=DEBUG

wrapper.syslog.loglevel=NONE


wrapper.single_invocation=true


wrapper.ntservice.name=SonarQube
wrapper.ntservice.displayname=SonarQube
wrapper.ntservice.description=SonarQube
wrapper.ntservice.dependency.1=
wrapper.ntservice.starttype=AUTO_START
wrapper.ntservice.interactive=false

wrapper.disable_restarts=TRUE
wrapper.ping.timeout=0
wrapper.shutdown.timeout=3000
wrapper.jvm_exit.timeout=3000
```

**Logs:**

```
Spawning intermediate process...<br>
Spawning daemon process...<br>
--> Wrapper Started as Daemon<br>
Using tick timer.<br>
server listening on port 32000.<br>
Command[0] : /usr/local/jdk1.8.0_45/bin/<br>
Command[1] : -Djava.awt.headless=true<br>
Command[2] : -Xms3m<br>
Command[3] : -Xmx32m<br>
Command[4] : -Djava.library.path=./lib<br>
Command[5] : -classpath<br>
Command[6] : ../../lib/jsw/wrapper-3.2.3.jar:../../lib/sonar-application-5.1.1.jar<br>
Command[7] : -Dwrapper.key=qGALrdnK2WooqXRW<br>
Command[8] : -Dwrapper.port=32000<br>
Command[9] : -Dwrapper.jvm.port.min=31000<br>
Command[10] : -Dwrapper.jvm.port.max=31999<br>
Command[11] : -Dwrapper.debug=TRUE<br>
Command[12] : -Dwrapper.pid=26746<br>
Command[13] : -Dwrapper.version=3.2.3<br>
Command[14] : -Dwrapper.native_library=wrapper<br>
Command[15] : -Dwrapper.service=TRUE<br>
Command[16] : -Dwrapper.cpu.timeout=10<br>
Command[17] : -Dwrapper.jvmid=1<br>
Command[18] : org.tanukisoftware.wrapper.WrapperSimpleApp<br>
Command[19] : org.sonar.application.App<br>
Launching a JVM...<br>
Unable to start JVM: Permission denied (13)<br>
Signal trapped.  Details:<br>
  signal number=17 (SIGCHLD), source="unknown"<br>
Received SIGCHLD, checking JVM process status.<br>
JVM process exited with a code of 1, setting the wrapper exit code to 1.<br>
JVM exited while loading the application.<br>
JVM Restarts disabled.  Shutting down.<br>
<-- Wrapper Stopped
```

Answer (score 23, accepted):

The problem is here:

```
Command[0] : /usr/local/jdk1.8.0_45/bin/
```

This is a configuration error; `java` is missing at the end here!

This seems to be the culprit line in your wrapper configuration:

```
# add /java at end
wrapper.java.command=/usr/local/jdk1.8.0_45/bin/java
```

in case of windows

```
wrapper.java.command=C:\Program Files\Java\jdk-11.0.6\bin\java
```

Comment: Had the same problem and fixed by correcting wrapper.java.command:

`wrapper.java.command=/path-to-jdk/bin/java`